# How to convert an integer into a character?

Tags: python, integer, character, chr, ord

I want to write a program that makes 0 into A, 1 into B, 2 into C, and so on, and I've tried just doing this:

```
def problem(number):
    return chr(number) - chr(0)
```

But no matter what my input is, I always get A.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Your posted code fails when it tries to subtract two strings (one character each).

Comment: `alphanum = ''.join(chr(n) for n in range(48, 123) if chr(n).isalnum()); table = str.maketrans(alphanum, alphanum[10:] + alphanum[:10]);print('12 Cats'.translate(table))` gives `BC Mk32`.

Comment: You should return chr(number - ord('0') + ord('A'))
You need a character, so the last step is always a chr() call

Answer (score 0):

```
import string

def problem(number):
    if number > len(string.ascii_uppercase):
        return None
    return string.ascii_uppercase[number]
```